# flip works, then doesn't, in Firefox; bring to front with click?

Tags: jquery, firefox, z-index, flip

all --

I'm putting together a page where multiple cards can drag and flip around independently, cobbling together code snippets I've found and adapted elsewhere and adding my own things here and there (the variable on getelementbyid, for example). [Here's the page so far](http://cheshiredave.com/cf/drag2.html).

Two questions:

1. It works in Safari and Chrome fine. The flip (though without animation) works in FF when you load the page, but as soon as you drag something, the flip stops working in FF altogether.
2. I've got it working so that dragging brings each card to the front. But I would also like to be able to push the flip button on each card and have it bring its card to the front. Right now if a card is behind and you push the button, it stays in the background.

Thanks for any help...